# MAKE: Path manipulation in makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

my project directory structure follows the pattern of foo/bar/baz/boo/
I want to find all foo's where boo=TEST
`mylist=$(dir $(shell find $(PRJPATH) -name TEST))` gives me a list of `$(PRJPATH)/foo/bar/baz/`

I am not able to make any progress beyond this point. How do I chop off the last two folder names from each element of mylist?

Note my ultimate goal is: Each foo folder contains a makefile, I want to run `make -C $(FOO folder)` only for those folders which have a */*/TEST sub folder

i.e.

```
$(mylist):
         make -C $@
verify: $(mylist)
         junit ....
```

**EDIT1**

A typical folder structure maybe

uart/basic/verif/TEST
spi/feature1/rtl_sim/TEST
pcie/dma/regression/TEST

mylist will then evaluate to the list (uart spi pcie)

Comment: Never use `make` when invoking a sub-make.  Always use the variable `$(MAKE)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I chop off the last two folder names from each element of mylist?

```
PRJPATH := /abs/path/to/project/root
mylist := $(PRJPATH)/foo1/bar1/baz1/ $(PRJPATH)/foo2/bar2/baz2/

# use abspath for dirty work
mychop2abs := $(abspath $(addsuffix /../..,$(mylist)))

# could transform to relative paths if needed
mychop2rel := $(patsubst $(PRJPATH)/%,%,$(mychop2abs))
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think `$(patsubst pattern,replacement,text)` can't be used here as it requires whitespace separated words in the text. So using make's `shell` command and call `sed` to remove the last two path components.

```
mypath=$(PRJPATH)/foo/bar/baz/
twodirsabove=$(shell echo "$(mypath)" | sed -E 's/[^/]+\/[^/]+\/$///')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is given a list of paths how do you remove the last three path elements in each?

You can do that with GNU make but it's annoying because of the way make's `dir` function works: it leaves the trailing slash which means subsequent `dir` functions as no-ops.  You can get around this with `patsubst`.  A handy thing is to make your own little function for that:

```
mydir = $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $1))
```

Now you can use:

```
mylist := $(call mydir,$(call mydir,$(call mydir $(shell find $(PRJPATH) -name TEST))))
```

Use `:=` here, it will be a lot faster.  (Note: untested).

Answer (score 0):

> I want to run `make -C $(FOO folder)` only for those folders which have
>   a `TEST/` sub folder

Find all the `TEST/` folders:

```
testdirs := $(shell find $(PRJPATH) -type d -name TEST)
```

This gives a list like `a/b/TEST c/TEST ./TEST` (say).

Now replace a trailing `/TEST` with `/Makefile`:

```
possible := ${testdirs:%/TEST=%/Makefile}
```

Leaving you with `a/b/Makefile c/Makefile ./Makefile`. Give this to `$(wildcard)`:

```
actual := $(wildcard ${possible})
```

giving a final answer of `c/Makefile ./Makefile` (`a/b/Makefile` didn't exist). Job done.

```
.PHONY: ${actual}
${actual}: ; ${MAKE} -C ${@D}
```

or some such.

**EDIT**

Ah, missed the subfolder bit. Well, if you only want a *Makefile* 3 dirs above the *TEST/* folder, just do

```
possible := ${testdirs:%/TEST=%/../../../Makefile}
```